# How can I make child entities always join?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity.

```java
class Parent {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = ..., fetch = ...)
    private List<Child> children;
}
```

Is there any hibernate specific annotation that telling to always `JOIN` the child entities while loading the parent, without the necessity of explicitly `JOIN`ing on querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`

This is the generated query

```
    select ...
    from
        parent parent0_ 
    left outer join
        child child0_
            on parent.id=child.parent_id 
    where
        parent.id=?
```

Note that remove `fetch` attribute from `@OneToMany` to tell Hibernate uses `@Fetch` as eager